# How to convert .OBJ 3D Mesh Georeferenced file generated from OpenDroneMap to .kmz format for Cesium?

Tags: kmz, cesium, 3d-model, mesh, opendronemap

I have Open Drone Map Output of a 3D Mesh Object file in .obj extension. I want to convert it into .kmz format to put it into Cesium Ion. How can I convert the files in the picture to a .kmz format file? [image]

Comment: KMZ isn't the best for Cesium, 3D Tiles (for huge models) or glTF / GLB (for reasonably sized models) would be better.  Can you just upload this OBJ to the Cesium ion online converter?  Or try obj2gltf to convert locally.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have tried to upload the obj file to Cesium, but Cesium is saying that it is not georeferenced. Can you please tell me how I can combine the files shown in the picture in the question to make one georeferenced file?